My ASP.NET Core Web App (Razor Pages or Web API) application doesn't want to deploy to Azure
If I create ASP.NET Core Web App (Razor Pages or Web API) with Docker then I get Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication5"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication5.dll"]

The Dockerfile be in the same place where is "csproj":

Now if I create pipeline (I choose "Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service") in Azure DevOps:

I get the pipeline:
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:

  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'b9242279-99b2-45f6-8096-ea3190c4f6ed'
  imageRepository: 'xxx'
  containerRegistry: 'xxx.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'xxx-auth'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - upload: manifests
      artifact: manifests

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'xxx.default'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)

          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/deployment.yml
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/service.yml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)

As a result when I try to deploy that application using the Azure pipelines I get the error:
##[error]Dockerfile:11
##[error]--------------------
##[error]   9 |     ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
##[error]  10 |     WORKDIR /src
##[error]  11 | >>> COPY ["WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
##[error]  12 |     RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
##[error]  13 |     COPY . .
##[error]--------------------
##[error]ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref c314f485-2f42-4ab2-8fcd-b39be4f6283c::vv9n5bzxz7yeebiyzmmvn6nk7: "/WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj": not found
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1

BUT if I move Dockerfile above and place it in the same place where is "csproj":

then I deploy my application successfully but I cannot run my application locally because I have the error:
No Dockerfile could be found. Please make sure you have a Dockerfile called 'Dockerfile' adjacent to the project file.

---------------------------------------------
----------- Change in Docker file: ----------
When I change Dockerfile from:
COPY ["WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]

to
COPY ["WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]

Final result:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication5"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication5.dll"]

Then I have a different error in Azure DevOps pipeline:
##[error]#7 extracting sha256:9cca61ea7dcde9e148fce1ff995332d2ad533b2d4c5927d344d6505a62bca6db
##[error]#7 extracting sha256:9cca61ea7dcde9e148fce1ff995332d2ad533b2d4c5927d344d6505a62bca6db 4.7s done
##[error]#7 extracting sha256:4369f7f50afbe743842fb8431f68ba4c280217854a444db13a563ca083f12d95
##[error]#7 extracting sha256:4369f7f50afbe743842fb8431f68ba4c280217854a444db13a563ca083f12d95 0.4s done
##[error]#7 DONE 10.6s
##[error]#10 [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src
##[error]#10 DONE 0.0s
##[error]#11 [build 3/7] COPY [WebApplication5.csproj, WebApplication5/]
##[error]#11 DONE 0.0s
##[error]#12 [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
##[error]#12 1.110   Determining projects to restore...
##[error]#12 2.325   Restored /src/WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj (in 771 ms).
##[error]#12 DONE 2.4s
##[error]#13 [build 5/7] COPY . .
##[error]#13 DONE 0.1s
##[error]#14 [build 6/7] WORKDIR /src/WebApplication5
##[error]#14 DONE 0.0s
##[error]#15 [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
##[error]#15 1.256   Determining projects to restore...
##[error]#15 1.839   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
##[error]#15 4.501 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj]
##[error]#15 4.514 
##[error]#15 4.515 Build FAILED.
##[error]#15 4.515 
##[error]#15 4.515 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj]
##[error]#15 4.516     0 Warning(s)
##[error]#15 4.516     1 Error(s)
##[error]#15 4.517 
##[error]#15 4.517 Time Elapsed 00:00:03.97
##[error]#15 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build \"./WebApplication5.csproj\" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
##[error]------
##[error] > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
##[error]1.839   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
##[error]4.501 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj]
##[error]4.514 
##[error]4.515 Build FAILED.
##[error]4.515 
##[error]4.515 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj]
##[error]4.516     0 Warning(s)
##[error]4.516     1 Error(s)
##[error]4.517 
##[error]4.517 Time Elapsed 00:00:03.97
##[error]------
##[error]Dockerfile:15
##[error]--------------------
##[error]  13 |     COPY . .
##[error]  14 |     WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication5"
##[error]  15 | >>> RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
##[error]  16 |     
##[error]  17 |     FROM build AS publish
##[error]--------------------
##[error]ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build \"./WebApplication5.csproj\" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Build and push an image to container registry


I have checked your YAML sample and the error message.
The cause of the issue is that when you use the Docker task in Azure DevOps Pipeline, the working directory will be set to the same path as the dockerfile by default.
And you have set the DockerfileContext  in the csproj file.
To solve the issues in the Pipeline, you need to keep the Dockerfile being in the SAME place as .csproj file.
Then you can modify the content in the dockerfile.
From
COPY ["WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]

TO
COPY ["WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]

For example:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication5"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication5.dll"]

In this case, you don't need to change any task settings in Azure Pipeline.
For another method, you can also change to use the script/bash task to run the docker command and set the working directory.
For example:
steps:
- script: 'docker build -f  WebApplication5/Dockerfile  -t imagenae .'
  workingDirectory: $(build.sourcesdirectory)

In this case, you can keep the current content of the dockerfile.
Update:
To solve the latest issue, you need to copy the project file to the path: /src/WebApplication5
For example:
COPY . /src/WebApplication5

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
COPY . /src/WebApplication5
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication5"
RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./WebApplication5.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication5.dll"]


Unfortunatelly then I have:  ##[error]  15 | >>> RUN dotnet build "./WebApplication5.csproj"

@AleksanderChelpski can you share more detailed error message?

I edited my original post and added details at the end :)

Let me check it. I will update as soon as possible.

@AleksanderChelpski Refer to the update in the answer. The dockerfile should help you solve the issue.

It works!! Thank you very much!! I marked your answer as helpful and solved :)
